# How to get Alphabetical section numbers with moderncv LateX package?

Tags: sectioning, tex-core, moderncv

There are some prior posts showing how to add section numbers of a moderncv document.

For example, the give code such as:

```
\newcounter{secnumber}
\renewcommand\sectionstyle[1]{{%
        \refstepcounter{secnumber}%
        \sectionfont
        \textcolor{color1}{\thesecnumber~#1}%
}}
```

and this does work in giving me section numbers.
My question is how (what changes to above code perhaps) to set these section numbers to be alphabetical and not numeric?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the instruction

```
\renewcommand\thesecnumber{\Alph{secnumber}}
```

immediately after

```
\newcounter{secnumber}
```

to get uppercase alphabetical symbols -- "A", "B", etc. -- instead of arabic numerals. If you want lowercase alphabetical symbols, use `\alph` instead of `\Alph`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! The same command does not work after the entire snippet. I guess I don't understand Tex well enough.

Comment: @Vin - You're welcome. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the same command does not work after the entire snippet", though. Did you run `\textcolor{color1}{\Alph{secnumber}~#1}`?